# Dense set of functions on manifold with no local optima

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, oc.optimization-and-control, morse-theory, global-optimization

Given a smooth manifold $M$ and another $S$, consider a smooth function $\psi: S \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and use this to define $\psi_s:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\phi_s(p):= \psi(s,p)$.

Further  assume that a dense set of $s \in S$ yield $\psi_s$ with no local optima on $M$, only a single global maximum, and a single global minimum. Then, is it true that for any $s$ for which there are critical points of $\psi_s$ besides the global max and min, these points can never be local optima with negative semi definite hessian?

Assuming compactness of $M$ is ok if needed, as is assuming all functions involved are bounded above and below and analytic (to exclude constant regions).

Comment: The lack of local optima does not prevent critical points which are not saddle (think x^3 near 0). Moreover, speaking of saddle points you seem to assume some differentiability, but you don't precise the regularity of your functions.

Comment: No, you can build 1D counterexamples, start out with an increasing $\phi$ and deform this into something that is constant on an interval, and then go back to the initial $\phi$.

Comment: That's not a counterexample to the question, perhaps I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I think I should have said, local optimum with negative semi definte hessian.

Comment: Edited to reflect this

Comment: Something like that. I think I just in an applied area where that's what "local optima" would mean to most people. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I'm really interested in if gradient ascent could be trapped at such a point, so flat doesn't cut it and isn't possible for other reasons in the application anyway.

Comment: The counterexample still works, just do it in 2 dimensions with a function $\phi_s(x)g(y)$, where $\phi_s$ is as above and $g$ has a strict extremum somewhere.

Comment: Do you still need constant on an interval?